Concrete slab over a shed window
Building an economy shed out of concrete blocks 8"x8"x16" and half blocks.
I am attaching a schematic drawing.
The shed base is square about 12.5' (9.5 blocks) each side.
Inside height is 10 blocks with the back wall 11 blocks.
The single slope roof will go from the back wall to the front wall.
I have made an opening for a door and a window. I have a tad weird window, dimensions 17"x48" and about 2" thin metal skirt around all the edges, to nail the window to the window frame. I want to place this window on the front wall. I am leaving a hole of dimension 55"x24" (3.5 blocks by 3 blocks) in the front wall where the window goes. I am at the last levels of the cinder block laying and it is time to think about the roof and all.
Here is the question: I want to build a concrete beam/slab above the window that will be 8"x8"x60"; this will be in the top (10th) block layer. The top plates will be placed on top at level 10 (and back wall at level 11 blocks).  I plan to make this beam out of quick-crete in a mold. But I wonder whether this beam whose volume is about 2.7 cubic feet will not break, because it is too long and it would rest by the 8" endings. Of course I would put rebar inside...
The top plates (I imagine 2"x8") would go on top layers and the front wall top as well. The roof is a gently one slope going down from 11 block wall to 10 block wall across 11ft. A couple of rafters or so would obviously go over the beam as well. I am exploring the possibility of a sheet metal roof.
If the concrete slab as I envision it is not suitable, what else should I put over the window where rafters would rest? Would just running the top plate (2"x8"x12') be good enough?
This is a rookie builder who has built a sturdy shed. I do not want to ruin it all by not doing the window opening right.

Concrete beams crossing empty space, should be made right, not really a DIY/rookie type of job.  A wooden header should be plenty to cross the window opening.  With the cement blocks, might want pressure treated wood.

Why do you want to use a concrete beam (lintel)?  What will your roof be made of?  What is your plan above the door?

@Huesmann The door is at the wall that will be parallel to the rafters. So I am thinking just to run the top plate over that whole wall in one piece (12 feet) and then build the door frame underneath. The height there is 10 blocks (say 78") and so if I build another concrete slab over the door then it would cut off a tall guy's head off.

@crip659 Well yes, even top experts were rookies one day and this project is certainly a learning experience. It may be its greatest value yet. Yes slabs over an open space is tricky, it is like building a bridge. I am thinking of putting well positioned rebars inside and have the slab box/form made in such a way that the bottom is treated wood and would remain with the slab and serve as (part of) the top of the window frame...
